# Server Side Rendering with Vue

Tags: server-side-rendering

I am a junior vue developer currently looking into server side rendering with Node.js. I have just started to use Nuxt but would like to set up SSR from scratch by myself to know how it actually works. I am really struggling to find any good resources or guides on the subject. The official vue docs are a bit too advanced for me and dont really explain how to fully set things up and the few examples I have found on the subject seem to be incomplete. I would really appreciate any pointers to good resources on this subject or any advice on where to look for a beginners guide to SSR

Comment: https://ssr.vuejs.org/

Comment: What server-side technology are you using? ASP.NET Core, plain Node, express?

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. I am using NODE with express and I have managed to get everything working after a lot of scraping round google and piecing things together